# How to post a local notification without sound in iOS 10?

Tags: ios, objective-c, localnotification, unnotificationrequest

```
    UNMutableNotificationContent *content = [[UNMutableNotificationContent alloc] init];
    content.sound = [UNNotificationSound defaultSound];
    NSDateComponents *components = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    components.hour = 0;
    UNCalendarNotificationTrigger *trigger = [UNCalendarNotificationTrigger triggerWithDateMatchingComponents:components repeats:YES];
    UNNotificationRequest *notificationRequest = [UNNotificationRequest requestWithIdentifier:kUserNotificationTag content:content trigger:trigger];
    [[UNUserNotificationCenter currentNotificationCenter] addNotificationRequest:notificationRequest withCompletionHandler:nil];
```

This is my code to post local notification in iOS10.When I set the sound is

```
[UNNotificationSound defaultSound]
```

or

```
[UNNotificationSound soundNamed:@""]
```

the sound of the notification is both the default sound.

but if I don't set the sound,the local notification will not work.

Does anybody have any ideas?Thanks so much!